# How to use a generator function as a callback inside of a event listener

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, frontend

I have a generator function that handles authentication and send a action to the redux store. 
That function needs to be executed on a event.

How can i use that as a callback inside of event listener?

That's the function:

```
export function* authentication({ data }) {
  // Data structure {
  //   action: 'authentication',
  //   id: '7293847829109932,
  //   displayName: 'User Name',
  //   avatar: 'https://steamcommunity.com/images/user.png',
  //   access: 'access_token_string',
  //   refresh: 'refresh_token_string',
  // }

  // Will dispatch the success action if the data is correct

  if (data.action === 'error') {
    return yield put(signInFailure(data.message));
  }
  if (data.action === 'authentication') {
    localStorage.setItem('dualbits:access', data.access);
    localStorage.setItem('dualbits:refresh', data.refresh);
  }

  return yield put(signInSuccess(data));
}
```

Event listener:

```
 window.addEventListener('message', authentication, false);
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a generator function? It always returns the first `yield` value anyway.

Comment: It's inside of a redux saga, so i have to dispatch an action and it has to be a generator

Comment: There's no reason to use a generator function here: you are always returning, which will end the iterator.

Comment: @LauraBeatris you need to use a normal function as the event listener, which should call the generator function to create the generator, and then *actually run the saga*.

Comment: @Bergi I did that and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I like these guys who say "I did it" and didn't leave an answer